# Remote Login Failure for User - Error No 18456

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2019, database-user

I setup a test user in a SQL Instance.

I tested logging in from within the Windows Server and it worked fine. So password is fine and permissions are fine.

From my PC I attempted to connect to SQL Server instance from SQL Management and this "Login Failed for User 18456" appears every time. I checked Windows firewall on the server and this seems fine. I escalated this with the server support team who too say their firewall has also been set to allow my IP address access to SQL Server ( I have to trust this guy as he seemed quite adamant).

I tested using telnet and no error message, just the blank screen... not sure if this is a good test or not though from browsing the internet this is a good indication the firewall is allowing access on port 1433.

I know the above login credentials work as I tested this (with Powershell and SQL Management from within Windows server). I also tested other credentials and that failed / worked too (PC / Windows respectively).

Normally when I have issues like this I am able to deal with firewall issues as I have admin access to the servers but on this occasion I do not and it is now becoming frustrating.

Not expecting much but I am becoming desperate now. Can someone help?

Comment: When you get a login failed error, network connectivity is successful. Are you connecting with Windows authentication? Is your PC a member of the same domain as the SQL Server? The SQL Server error log should have additional info about the cause of the login failure. Add that error message to your question.

Comment: No my PC is not part of that same domain. I thought about this and added the domain credentials  in "Manage your credentials": "<SQL Instance>:1433" and username "DOMAIN\username". This still did not work but I suspect there is something I have not included.

Comment: I did check the logs and nothing in the logs indicates any failed attempts with same credentials.

Comment: check microsofts troubleshouting side https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15   and follow the steps

Comment: Did you fully-qualify the server name in credential manager?

Comment: I did follow the Microsoft's troubleshooting, yes, though I will be going through that again later.

Comment: @DanGuzman did you mean "DOMAIN\<SQL Instance>:1433" or the "DOMAIN\username"? The latter yes, did not know you could do the same in the "Internet or network address".

Comment: I appreciate the help here. I suspect from what you're saying that it is more than likely a network domain issue which is about as much as I thought it would be... I may continue investigating with this in mind.

Comment: @Rob, I mean the server name should to be a FQDN (e.g. yoursqlserver.yourcompany.com:1433).